# How can I use jQuery to add content before the end of a DIV?

Tags: jquery

I have the following DIV in my code:

```
<div class="controls-buttons">
  ....
  ....
</div>
```

How can I use jQuery to append the following two links:

```
   <a id="level-1">1</a>
   <a id="level-12">12</a>
```

to the end of the code that is within the DIV? So the end
result is this:

```
<div class="controls-buttons">
   ...
   ...
   <a id="level-1">1</a>
   <a id="level-12">12</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method:

```
$('.controls-buttons')
    .append('<a id="level-1">1</a>')
    .append('<a id="level-12">12</a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `append` function:

```
$('div.controls-buttons').append('<a id="level-1">1</a><a id="level-12">12</a>');
```